# A construction of the fundamental solution for Schroedinger equations

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, schrodinger-operators

Does someone know some book or lecture notes useful for the reading of the paper

"A construction of the fundamental solution for the Schrödinger equation",     Fujiwara, Daisuke, *J. Analyse Math.* 35 (1979), 41–96 ?

In particular I'm looking for references for a better understanding of the concepts of  Feynman's path integral and the construction of the parametrices.